# Unpacking multiple entries as a string for `fields` in Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm making a helper function file to interact with a local database to allow interaction with the database in a programmatic way.

I have 2 functions:

```
import pymysql
def conn_db(host, port, user, password, database):
    #conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, passwd=password, db=database)
    dbcursor = conn.cursor()
    return dbcursor

def select_from_table(fields, table):
    #dbcursor.execute(SELECT <fields> from table)
    dbcursor.execute()   #STUCK HERE
```

I'm wondering how I can allow multiple entries for the `fields` parameter in `select_from_table` which would represent columns in the backend database (see STUCK HERE)

for instance, an example of a use of this function I am trying to achieve is: I want to execute using `select_from_table()`:
`select_from_table([id, name, address], person)` where it'd be selecting both the `id`, `name`, and `address` from the `person` table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply trying to use `*args`. You can do the following:

```
def select_from_table(table, *fields):
    query = "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(",".join(fields), table)
    dbcursor.execute(query)
```

For more information on `*args` and `**kwargs` check out this question here [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Been awhile since I used `args` i'll have to brush up on it again